# FPGA multiple firmwares on one serial flash memory (intel/altera)

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

Preloaded more than one firmware to flash memory.

Can I make the FPGA reboot during its operation and start loading its firmware not from the beginning of the flash drive, but from a different memory area?

This loads a different firmware preset.

Comment: I know it is possible to do it in Xilinx using the icap module.
I am guessing that it should be for Intel

Answer (score 1):

The "Remote Update Intel FPGA IP" has some capabilities; see [Remote Update Intel FPGA IP User Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altremote.pdf).